# Create a DataGridView out of a Xml File while using certain Elements as ColumnHeader

Tags: c#, datagridview

I currently have a XmlFile which look like the following (Note: the structure of this xmlFile is final) :

```
<Language>
  <FileInfo NumberOfEntries="10" FileCreationTime="2017-07-14 12:23:07" />
  <Entry Key="ABC_DEF_GHI" CreationTime="01.01.0001 00:00:00" LastModifiedTime="01.01.0001 00:00:00">
    <LanguageEntry>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Value>Hallo</Value>
      <Comment>
      </Comment>
      <Mark>
      </Mark>
    </LanguageEntry>
    <LanguageEntry>
      <ID>2</ID>
      <Value>Hello</Value>
      <Comment>
      </Comment>
      <Mark>
      </Mark>
    </LanguageEntry>
    ...
  </Entry>
  ...
</Language>
```

For now the only thing that matters are the Keys, which are given to one Entry, the ID and the Value.

I want to create a DataGridView which looks like the following:

```
Key        | 1       | 2       | ID3     |...
---------------------------------------------
ABC_DEF_GHI|Hallo    |Hello    |someValue|...
---------------------------------------------
XYZ_DAF_ABC|someValue|someValue|someValue|...
     .          .         .         .   
     .          .         .         .
     .          .         .         .
```

How can I achieve it, to make my DataGridView look like the one i showed above?
I tried using standard DataSet implementations, but I just can not think of a way of doing it. Please leave a comment, if you need any further information on what i try to get to or if something is unclear.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to deserialize your data. In order to achive this you should have these classes.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "FileInfo")]
public class FileInfo
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "NumberOfEntries")]
    public string NumberOfEntries { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "FileCreationTime")]
    public string FileCreationTime { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "LanguageEntry")]
public class LanguageEntry
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ID")]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Comment")]
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Mark")]
    public string Mark { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Entry")]
public class Entry
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "LanguageEntry")]
    public List<LanguageEntry> LanguageEntry { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Key")]
    public string Key { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "CreationTime")]
    public string CreationTime { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "LastModifiedTime")]
    public string LastModifiedTime { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Language")]
public class Language
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "FileInfo")]
    public FileInfo FileInfo { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Entry")]
    public Entry Entry { get; set; }
}
```

And then you have to generate dynamic columns according to your data:

```
private void GenerateColumnsAndData(Language language)
{
        var countIds = language.Entry.LanguageEntry.Count;

        dataGridView1.ColumnCount = countIds + 1;

        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Key";

        for (int i = 0; i < language.Entry.LanguageEntry.Count; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Columns[i+1].Name = language.Entry.LanguageEntry[i].ID;
        }

        ArrayList row = new ArrayList();

        row.Add(language.Entry.Key);

        foreach (var item in language.Entry.LanguageEntry)
        {
            row.Add(item.Value);
        }

        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row.ToArray());
}
```

Finally here's an example:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

        string xml = @"<Language>
            <FileInfo NumberOfEntries=""10"" FileCreationTime=""2017-07-14 12:23:07"" />
            <Entry Key=""ABC_DEF_GHI"" CreationTime=""01.01.0001 00:00:00"" LastModifiedTime=""01.01.0001 00:00:00"">
                <LanguageEntry>
                    <ID>1</ID>
                    <Value>Hallo</Value>
                    <Comment>
                    </Comment>
                    <Mark>
                    </Mark>
                </LanguageEntry>
                <LanguageEntry>
                    <ID>2</ID>
                    <Value>Hello</Value>
                    <Comment>
                    </Comment>
                    <Mark>
                    </Mark>
                </LanguageEntry>
                </Entry>
                </Language>";         

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Language));

        using(TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            Language result = (Language)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            GenerateColumnsAndData(result);
        }
  }
```

or if you are reading from a file try this:

```
 using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("MyFilePath", FileMode.Open))
 {
      Language result = (Language)serializer.Deserialize(fileStream);
      GenerateColumnsAndData(result);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I just had to make some little changes, to use my .xml file! I really like this solution.